# Threading with WebView and HTTPClient in JellyBean

Tags: android, webview, httpclient

I'm trying to call and URL using HTTPClient, modify the contents, and then set the data using webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(), however I'm having problems with the threading.

If I make the HTTPGet call on the main UI thread, I receive a fatal error with android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

If I make the call in a new thread, and set the value to the webView in that thread, I get a warning in the logs saying: "All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads."

And if I make the call in a separate thread and set it in a class variable and publish to the webView on the main thread, then the loadDataWithBaseURL() doesn't ever get the data that I call in a separate thread because it seems to occur before the other thread finishes the call.

So the question is: how do I get the contents in a separate thread, and load them in the webView on the main thread?

```
public class Browser extends Activity {
public final String CLASS_TAG = "ScoutBrowser";
public WebView webView;
final Activity activity = this;
public String webContent;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

    webView = getWebView();


    Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "Loaded App...");
}

private WebView getWebView() {
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            if (progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    view.setWebViewClient(new MyViewerClient());
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webContent = "<html><body>initialized...</body></html>";
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               webContent = callURL();
               WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
               view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.somewebsite.com", webContent, "text/html", null, null);

           }
    }).start(); 

    //view.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.somewebsite.com", webContent, "text/html", null, null);


    return view;
}

public String callURL(){
    String content = "<html><body>loading...</body></html>";

    //Creates web clientclient
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Create a local instance of cookie store
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    // Create local HTTP context
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.somewebsite.com/"); 

    //System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG,"executing request " + httpget.getURI());


    // Pass local context as a parameter
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            content = convertInputStream(instream);
            //tv.setText(content);

        }

        Log.d(CLASS_TAG,"Response Code: "+code+" - "+reason);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(CLASS_TAG,"ProtocolException",e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(CLASS_TAG,"IOException",e);
    }
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG, webContent);
    return content;
}

public String convertInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line);
        }
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the run method in your new Thread, post it back to the UI thread with one of the methods here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Other options are keep a variable pointing to your thread and call join() on it, or use a FutureTask.